# Laravel Mix + Vue-Loader 15

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having some difficulties configuring my webpack config correctly  .

I am using these following versions:

```
$ npm -v
6.2.0    

$ npm info vue-loader version
15.2.6    

$ npm info babel-loader version
7.1.5    

$ npm info laravel-mix version
2.1.11    

$ npm info vue2-datatable-component version
2.3.1    

$ npm info babel version
6.23.0
```

I am recieving this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue2-datatable-component/src/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (38:59)    

  36 |   created () {
  37 |     // init query (make all the properties observable by using `$set`)
> 38 |     const q = { limit: 10, offset: 0, sort: '', order: '', ...this.query }
     |                                                            ^
  39 |     Object.keys(q).forEach(key => { this.$set(this.query, key, q[key]) })
  40 |   },
  41 |   watch: {    

 @ ./node_modules/vue2-datatable-component/src/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-139 1:160-296
 @ ./node_modules/vue2-datatable-component/src/index.vue
 @ ./node_modules/vue2-datatable-component/src/main.js
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js
```

Here is the config that I have in my laravel mix file:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: file => (
                  /node_modules/.test(file) &&
                  !/\.vue\.js/.test(file)
                )
              }
          ],

      },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
});
```

It looks like babel isn't running in the vue component files but when I remove the exclude setting in the rule above I still get the same error.

I have been trying to fix this all weekend and am at a dead end.

Comment: Update: I am still unable to find a solution. I have since just reverted back to Vue-Loader 14.2.2

Comment: I know this is a year old, but you should have latest NodeJS for this to work, not 6 but 10 or more.